# VB.Net App Stuck in Loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would just like the program to end itself.
Application.Exit just keeps rolling me back in a loop.
EDITED to Include Code::
    Module Module 1

```
Sub Main()
  Sub1()
  Sub2()
End Sub

Sub1()
EndSub

Sub2()
End Sub

End Module
```

EDIT: It seems to be looping back here to Sub ChooseDomain2.. I am including Sub 1 as well.

```
Sub ChooseDomain1()
    Dim DomainName As Object
    'Get List of all users on Domain using WinNT 
    DomainName = InputBox(messageOK, Title, defaultValue)
    de.Path = "WinNT://****".Replace("****", DomainName)
    If DomainName Is "" Then ChooseDomain2() Else StoreUserData1()
End Sub


Sub ChooseDomain2()
    MsgBox("Welcome to the Domain Searcher. Click OK to Auto Search for Domain")
    Dim MsgBoxResult As Object = ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain.Name
    MsgBoxResult = InputBox(messageCan, Title, MsgBoxResult)
    de.Path = "WinNT://*****".Replace("*****", MsgBoxResult)
    StoreUserData1()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you calling Application.Exit?  The code you listed above does not loop back, it runs once then closes.

Comment: Not on My computer...I have tried it with Application.Ext After the last Sub, in Last Sub, before Module end, etc etc. With or without it I get taken Back to Sub1, after everything is done...

Comment: What kind of project is this?  Console Application?

Comment: How do you know that its going back to "square one"?

Comment: Part one of my program asks for the user to input some information. Last part runs that information. After it runs the information it outputs the correct file etc etc. Then asks for a file again

Comment: It sounds like the loop is in one of your functions, are you calling Sub1() inside of Sub2()?  It would really help to see the actual code.  Maybe when you get back to your computer you can post it.

Comment: It will be a while until I can Post it but I will when I get to it. Its a ton of code..6 or 7 Subs. Prolly not the best constructed code, so it could be that. I feel like I checked that but who knows.

Comment: Added last subs code. Will add more as I look through it again myself.

Comment: Added more code. I cant even seem to crash my own program with app.exit. How robust!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Exit` is not required as the console app will quit after it finishes executing the last line in Sub Main. As previously mentioned it is likely you have Sub1 calling Sub2 (or something similar), so set a breakpoint on the start of each sub to find which one is continually being called. Then you can do a search in your code to find where this sub is being called from.

Answer (score 1):

> When it hits end Module it Just starts back from Square one.

Modules don’t execute at all – so it never “hits end module” and never starts “from square one”. Modules merely group methods that can be executed, and `Main` is a special method that serves as the start of your application.

That said, your code is guaranteed (!) not to execute repeatedly. Also, there is no `Application.Exit` anywhere in your code so it’s hard to see what you are *actually* executing. Not the code you showed, anyway.

Note that VB potentially executes code that you didn’t write (code can be auto-generated by the compiler, in particular the application framework) but this doesn’t seem to be happening in your case, and shouldn’t loop in any case. But again, this is impossible to say from the information you have given.

Comment: So I shouldn't even need application.exit? and the code above should just end? So in other words you second smoore's comment?

Comment: @harper89 Almost never. `Application.Exit` is a pathological hard-stop. It’s a bit like crashing your application from within (well, not quite as drastic, but you usually terminate a program by more controlled means, i.e. just leaving the main method).